# Continuously multiply it by itself? such as 2^(100)

Tags: list, printing, range

I want to print a list of numbers that show exponent of 2 to the 100th power such as 2,4,8,16,32,64,128.... up to the 100th power of two using a FOR loop and printing it. I basically want to multiply 2x2x2...100 times

for i in range(1,101,1):
    print (i)

2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
etc.. all the way to 2^(100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly faster

```
power=2
for i in range(1,101,1):
    power*=2
    print(power)
```

Comment: Excellent, Thank you Gino